# Assign Variable to another Variable and have changes in one be mirrored in the other

Tags: c#

Is it possible to assign a variable to another variable and when you change the second variable the change waterfalls down to the first variable?

Like this.

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
b = 1;
```

now both b and a would = 1.

The reason I ask this is because I have 4 objects I'm keeping track of, and I keep track of each using a 5th object called currentObject that equals whichever of the 4 objects the user is using. However, I would like to just make a change to the currentObject and just have it waterfall to the variable it came from.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *objects*, *references* and *variables*. If you have two different variables (which aren't aliased via ref/out in a method, etc) then those will be independent.

However, if two variables refer to the same *object* (i.e. their type is a class, and their **values** are equal references), then any changes to that object will be visible via either variable. It sounds like this is what you want to achieve. For example:

```
public class SomeMutableClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Two independent variables which have the same value
SomeMutableClass x1 = new SomeMutableClass();
SomeMutableClass x2 = x1;

// This doesn't change the value of x1; it changes the
// Name property of the object that x1's value refers to
x1.Name = "Fred";
// The change is visible *via* x2's value.
Console.WriteLine(x2.Name); // Fred
```

If you're not entirely comfortable with how reference types and objects work, you may wish to read my [article about them](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html).

EDIT: One analogy I often use is of a house. Suppose we have two pieces of paper (variables). The same house address is written on both pieces of paper (that's the *value* of each variable, the *reference*). There's only one house. If someone uses the first piece of paper to get to the house, then paints the door red, they're not changing anything about their piece of paper - they're changing something about the *house*. Then if someone uses the *second* piece of paper to get to the house, they'll see the front door is red too. There's only one house, however many pieces of paper have its address written on them.

Comment: Will this also work if I change x2.Name value? Will it then change the value of x1.Name?

Comment: @JMD: Yes - because you're not really "changing x2.Name" - you're changing the Name property of the sole object, and you happen to be accessing that object via `x2`.

Comment: Thanks for updating with the analogy. I understand how it is supposed to work more clearly now, but I'm still a bit confused as to its implementation. So x1 and x2 are the pieces of paper in your analogy, but what is the house? I thought the class was more like the blueprint for the house, and we need to instantiate a new object of those blueprints.

Comment: @JMD: The *instance* of `SomeMutableClass` (created with `new SomeMutableClass()`) is the object in question. Have you read the article I linked to as well? You might also want to find a good introductory C# book - it's really important to understand this topic thoroughly.

Comment: I've been programming professionally for four years now, but not once have I ever needed to do this. :) I did read your article as well, but it's just a slightly confusing topic for me. I feel like your code is what I'm already doing, but my code is across several files and is thousands of lines, so I might be missing something here. I'll investigate to see if what I'm doing is what you have here.

Comment: ok, so what I'm doing is this. I have `x1 = new someMutableCLass()` and then `x2` also equals `new someMutalbleClass()`, but later I then have `x2 = x1`. Would this produce the same result as what you have? Also, what if I have `x2 = x1` right off the bat, but later change it to `x2=x3` where `x3` already equals `new someMutableCLass()`?

Comment: @JMD: why don't you try it? Think about what you believe it should do (after reading the linked article) then test it with a short console app.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks again for all the help. I was actually doing it this way already, but I was foolishly resetting the object in some random piece of code. The bright side of this is now I actually understand why the code I wrote works, thanks to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you should understand what you are doing in your previous code

1. Create a 4-byte-sized variable named "a" in memory and after that give it a value of 0
2. Create a 4-byte-sized variable named "b" in memory and after that give it a value of (a)'s value [Currently 0]
3. Change the Value of the variable "b" to 1

But this isn't what you want, what you want is something more like this

1. Create a 4-byte-sized variable named "a" in memory and after that give it a value of 0
2. Create a 4-byte-sized variable named "b" in memory and after that change the address of the variable "b" so that it doesn't refer to these 4 bytes anymore,but instead refer to (a)'s 4 bytes

What you are asking for is both Bad + Impossible

- Bad : you have just created an empty space of 4 bytes that have no use at all and completely ignored them
- Impossible : Because you can't change the address of a value type (thus they are called "value" types not "reference" types)

But what you "Should" be asking for is this

1. Create a 4-byte-sized variable named "a" in memory and after that give it a value of 0
2. Create an address that refers to the variable a
3. Change the value of a through this address

And this approach is actually totally OK, and it uses [Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx), Pointers simply are addresses in memory.

Note : To use pointers you have to Allow unsafe code in Project > Build

In code here is how to do it :

```
int a = 5;
unsafe //use unsafe around the areas where pointers exist
{
    int* b = &a; //create an address named b that refers to a
    *b = 1; //change the value of the variable that exists at the address b to 1

    //now a = 1
}
```

Comment: +1  for having an solution that sticks closer to the original purpose, instead of having to change code around to use SomeMutableClass instead of plain ints.  (in my case flagged enums).

Answer (score 4):

With struct/value types ------- **NO**

like int, boolean, double etc.

With Reference types -------- **YES**

like classes, objects etc.

Comment: Note that this *doesn't* really mean that changes to a *variable* are visible to a different variable. It's all in terms of *objects*.

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is a design pattern commonly know as observer. An object B will monitor an object A (or 4 objects since this is what u need) and when A is modified, B is notified and update its state accordingly.

In the case of C#, I would use events. For example, define event ValueChanged on A. B would listen to this event and update its value.

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

Class A
{
   public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
   int val = 0;
   int Val
   {
      get { return val;}
      set { 
          if ( val != value ) val = value
          {
              val = value;
              if (Changed != null) Changed(this, new EventArgs());
          }

   }
}


class B
{
    A obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;
    int Val {get;set;}
    A CurrentlyWatched {get;set;}

    public B()
    {
       obj1 = new A();
       obj1.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ElementChanged);
       obj2 = new A(); 
       ...
    }

    private void ElementChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         this.CurrentlyWatched = sender as A;
         this.Val = CurrentlyWatched.Val;
      }
}
```

Comment: But at any one time I don't know which of the 4 objects currentObject points to, so if I do this, how will I know which of the 4 objects to update when currentObject is modified?

Comment: the sender object is the last element that triggered the event, you can keep track of it in another variable. See the updated code

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but there are a couple ways I'd handle this scenario.

First, you could create private variables and then have public getters/setters that modify the private values as desired:

```
private int firstVar = 10;
private int secondVar = 20;

public int FirstVar
{
    get
    {
        return firstVar;
    }
    set
    {
        firstVar = secondVar = value;
    }
}
public int SecondVar
{
    get
    {
        return secondVar;
    }
    set
    {
        firstVar = secondVar = value;
    }
}

public void SomeFunction()
{
    Console.WriteLine("FirstVar=" + FirstVar); // Output: "FirstVar=10"
    Console.WriteLine("SecondVar=" + SecondVar); // Output: "SecondVar=20"

    FirstVar = 30;
    Console.WriteLine("FirstVar=" + FirstVar); // Output: "FirstVar=30"
    Console.WriteLine("SecondVar=" + SecondVar); // Output: "SecondVar=30"
}
```

Another way would be to create a custom class that can do the same thing:

```
    public class MyVariable
    {
        protected static List<MyVariable> _instances;

        public int Value { get; set; }

        public MyVariable() 
        {
            if (_instances == null) _instances = new List<MyVariable>();
            _instances.Add(this);
        }
        public MyVariable(int value) : base() { Value = value; }

        public void SetAll(int value) { foreach (MyVariable myVar in _instances) myVar.Value = value; }
        public override string ToString() { return Value.ToString(); }
    }

    public void SomeOtherFunction()
    {
        MyVariable var1 = new MyVariable(30);
        MyVariable var2 = new MyVariable(50);

        Console.WriteLine("var1=" + var1.ToString()); // Output: "var1=30"
        Console.WriteLine("var2=" + var2.ToString()); // Output: "var2=50"

        var1.SetAll(100);
        Console.WriteLine("var1=" + var1.ToString()); // Output: "var1=100"
        Console.WriteLine("var2=" + var2.ToString()); // Output: "var2=100"
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Here you go you can change the code in the get and set functions to do pretty much anything.  You can not declare this in a function however.

```
    int a;
    int b
    {
        get
        {
            return a;
        }
        set
        {
            a = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is I do not know which of the 4 objects the user is currently using. B doesn't always just equal a, i could equal one of 4 other ints.

Comment: like i said you can write anything you want in the get and set functions including choosing between 4 variables. My origonal post was just a syntax layout for you to run with but I edited it to better show my point since you didn't follow where I was going.