# ICollection.Clear remove data from copy object

Tags: c#, .net

```
MyRequest copyRequest = new MyRequest(); 
copyRequest = request; 
copyRequest.MyList.Clear();
```

I have above codes

MyList is a list of strings

When I call copyRequest.MyList.Clear()

it also clears request.MyList.

Is there any way to clear only copyRequest.MyList

Comment: MyRequest is not  ICollection but  MyRequest. MyList is ICollection

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
MyRequest copyRequest = new MyRequest(); 
copyRequest = request;
```

...does not create a copy of `request`. It just reassigns the reference of `request` so it is one object with 2 aliases and the instance created with the `new` operator will be GCd as it has no references.

You need to implement `IClonable` which will then be responsible for creating a deep-copy of your `MyRequest` object, including the items of `MyList`.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `IClonable`. Microsoft 2003: _"Do not implement ICloneable"_ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx

Comment: Simplest way to create copy: `var copyRequest = requrest.ToList();` or `var copyRequest = new List(request);`

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: `request` and `copyRequest` are not a `List<T>` but `MyRequest`.

Comment: Do u think ToList() make it a separate memory?

Comment: Also, why should OP create a deep copy of the list if all he wants is to clear that list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter to match his expectations :)

Comment: @KuttanSujith: `Enumerable.ToList` create a new list from the original sequence, but all objects in the new list are the same references as in the old list. However, `request` is not a list but a `MyRequest` object, so i don't understand how `ToList` helps or is possible if `MyRequest` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning the `request` to `copyRequest` both variables refer to the same objects. So if you then clear the list that affects to all variables referencing this object.

You have to create a new `MyRequest` and assign all related objects from the original request to the "copied". I assume the list is empty by default, so you don't need to assign and clear it.

```
MyRequest copyRequest = new MyRequest(); 
copyRequest.Property1 = request.Property1;
copyRequest.Property2 = request.Property2;
copyRequest.Property3 = request.Property3;
```

Since [J. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604165/284240) explains much better the difference of references and variables here's a quote:

> One analogy I often use is of a house. Suppose we have two pieces of
>   paper (variables). The same house address is written on both pieces of
>   paper (that's the value of each variable, the reference). There's only
>   one house. If someone uses the first piece of paper to get to the
>   house, then paints the door red, they're not changing anything about
>   their piece of paper - they're changing something about the house.
>   Then if someone uses the second piece of paper to get to the house,
>   they'll see the front door is red too. There's only one house, however
>   many pieces of paper have its address written on them.

More detailed: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're copying a reference, not the contents of `MyList`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve in the code, but it looks like what you want is a new `MyRequest` that is identical to the original except for the `MyList`, which you want to be emtpy.  What you might want to do then is create a method that produces a new `MyRequest` without an empty `MyList`.

Bear in mind, though, that any reference in `MyRequest` will behave much the same way as `MyList` does.  I.e., if `Property1` is a reference type, the following

```cs
myResultCopy.Property1 = myResultOriginal.Property1
```

will result in `myResultCopy.Property1` and `myResultOriginal.Property1` referring to the same instance.  So any change to `myResultCopy.Property1` will be seen by users of `myResultOriginal.Property1`.