# C# Making 2 variables equal one another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I made this code which should make it so that the variables `current` and `levelclicks` equal one another. However when I run the code that is not the case.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    public int current;
    public int levelclicks;




    public void IncreaseValue()
    {
        levelclicks = levelclicks + 1;

    }

    void LevelUp()
    {
        levelclicks = current;

    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there's nothing wrong with the code, but if there is then please tell me.

Comment: how do you examine they are not equal? How do you call these two functions?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I added the `IncreaseValue` to a button when its clicked and when I click it I can see that `levelclicks` changes in the unity inspector, however `current` does not change.

Comment: integers are value-types, not referenceä-types. So changing one doesn't affect the other. You'd need to set the other variable as well. See this post, which goes into detail about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604136/assign-variable-to-another-variable-and-have-changes-in-one-be-mirrored-in-the-o

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain even if those were reference types, he's changing the reference, not the object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

`current` and `levelclicks` are two int, which is a value type (a `struct`). That means than each of those fields have an independant value.

So what `levelclicks = current;` does is copy the value of `current` into `levelclicks`.
And what `levelclicks = levelclicks + 1;` does is increase the value of `levelclicks`. It doesn't change the value of `current`.

### Why it wouldn't work even if it was a reference type

Even if you used a reference type (a `class`), that still wouldn't work, but for another reason.

`levelclicks = current;` would indeed make both fields reference the same object, and if you modify this object through one reference, even accessing it through the other reference would give you the modified object.

BUT with `levelclicks = levelclicks + 1;` you would get the object referenced by `levelclicks`, create another object with the +1, and save a reference to this new object in `levelclicks`. Then `levelclicks` and `current` would not reference the same object anymore.

However, if you could modify the object in memory instead of creating a new object, it would work. But then, you wouldn't have to save the reference (since the reference didn't change). It would just be something like `levelclicks.Add(1);` and that method would be return `void`.

### Back to what you want to do.

Why do you want two different variables with the same value? If you have a good reason, beneath `levelclicks = levelclicks + 1;`, you could add

- `current = current + 1;`
- `current = levelclicks;`